# Where is "Perthall"?

Tags: historical-gazetteer, staffordshire, location

In looking at this source for Edward Dickinson, it states he is from Perthall (presumably in the UK). I don't find such a place on the map.

Where would it be?

https://www.dulwichpicturegallery.org.uk/explore-the-collection/551-600/mrs-benjamin-west-ii-with-her-son-benjamin-west-iii/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Benjamin West, Jr.](https://npg.si.edu/object/npg_12.581) was the son of Benjamin West, the artist.

"Perthall" is likely a misreading of "Pershall," an estate and family in Staffordshire that is well-documented. The misreading is due to the 1700s-early 1800s use of the "long s" which can be mistaken for an "f" or a "t":

[image: Pershall with long s]

[Universal Magazine of Knowledge and Pleasure  1772-12: Vol 51 Iss 357](https://archive.org/details/sim_new-universal-magazine-or-miscellany_1772-12_51_357/page/n33/mode/2up?q=perthall)

[image: another example of Pershall with long s]

[The Caledonian Mercury  1730-07-06: Iss 1597](https://archive.org/details/sim_caledonian-mercury_1730-07-06_1597/page/n1/mode/2up?q=perthall)

The misspelling "Perthall" also appears in Robert C. Alberts' [*Biography of Benjamin West*](https://archive.org/details/benjaminwestbiog00albe_0/page/306/mode/2up?q=perthall).

The "[England, Staffordshire, Church Records, 1538-1944](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QLQB-WBDC)" database shows that Mary Dickinson of **Eccleshall, Stafford** obtained a license to marry Benjamin West at Atcham, Shropshire.

The [Pershall estate](https://goo.gl/maps/WFRdQ7xvgVJs4b2s8) is about 1 mile outside the town of Eccleshall. [Some](https://historicengland.org.uk/listing/the-list/list-entry/1374232) of the [Pershall buildings](https://historicengland.org.uk/listing/the-list/list-entry/1180329) are [listed](https://historicengland.org.uk/listing/the-list/list-entry/1180332) in the National Heritage List for England.

The wedding was noted in the [Monthly Register and Encyclopedian Magazine  1803-09-01: Vol 3 Iss 17](https://archive.org/details/sim_monthly-register-and-encyclopedian-magazine_1803-09-01_3_17/page/276/mode/2up?q=pershall):

[image: wedding of Benjamin West to Miss Dickenson of Pershall]

Transcription:

> Shropshire. Married. -- At Atcham, Benjamin West, esq. to Miss Dickenson, of Pershall, near Stafford, a most beautiful and accomplished young lady, with a fortune of 30,000l.

This [inflation calculator](https://www.in2013dollars.com/uk/inflation/1803?amount=30000) tells me that £30,000 is worth £3,286,021.53 in 2022, so Miss Dickenson/Dickinson was also quite wealthy.

Comment: Great answer, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

[The Gentleman's Magazine, Volume 73, Issue 2](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=oSA7DKRlbKYC&pg=PA691&lpg=PA691&dq=%22perthall%22%20staffordshire&source=bl&ots=KC6UQnUg2T&sig=ACfU3U0CjmXj-uby_8XDzH2GrOraSxHr9Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiH-ce06vj2AhVV4jgGHXLiBPsQ6AF6BAgHEAM#v=onepage&q=%22perthall%22%20staffordshire&f=false) (1803) suggests that Perthall is/was near Stafford in Staffordshire:

[image]